# usar uma url de um servidor postegresql no prisma

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, postgresql, next.js

Quero usar uma URL de um servidor para o banco de dados
como eu faço para substituir o `.env` com  o database url

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:Espanha12@@localhost:5432/thedoctors?schema=public"
```

preciso substituir o database local por um servidor online

por esse servidor => thedoctsdb.postgresql.dbaas.com.br

quero usar uma url de um servidor para o banco de dados
como eu faço para substituir o .env com  o database URL

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:Espanha12@@localhost:5432/thedoctors?schema=public"
```

preciso substituir o database local por um servidor online

por esse servidor => thedoctsdb.postgresql.dbaas.com.br

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema seria substituindo o seu valor atualmente contendo `localhost` pelo endereço do host.

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html) temos a seguinte regra de formação de um URI para conexão:

```
postgresql://[userspec@][hostspec][/dbname][?paramspec]

onde userspec é:

user[:password]

e hostspec é:

[host][:port][,...]

e paramspec é:

name=value[&...]
```

Desta forma, supondo que a sua variável declarada em seu arquivo `.env` possui o valor que postou em sua pergunta temos:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:Espanha12@@localhost:5432/thedoctors?schema=public"
```

Desta forma, se seguirmos a documentação, devemos ter a seguinte URI para sua conexão:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:Espanha12%40@thedoctsdb.postgresql.dbaas.com.br:5432/thedoctors?schema=public"
```

Repare que em sua URI original, existem dois arrobas (<kbd>@</kbd>) neste caso estou supondo que não é um erro de digitação o primeiro arroba considero um caractere da senha, e o segundo será o separador do [userspec] do [hostspec] (este é obrigatório e não deve ser escapado). Neste caso então será necessário fazer o `url escaping` do seu caractere no padrão utilizado pelos navegadores. No caso do arroba o correto seria `%40`.

Perceba que é obrigatório ter um arroba não espa

Veja o destaque em uma tradução livre:

> Percent-encoding deve ser usado para incluir símbolos com  significado especial em qualquer parte da URI, exemplo dado, substitua <kbd>=</kbd> com <kbd>%3D</kbd>.

Comment: obrigada !!! deu certo